# Where do people make their backgrounds?

Tags: android, image

I am building an application and currently am in the process of add backgrounds in. The way I make the backgrounds are by designing it in Microsoft Word and then pasting it into Paint then saving it as a .png file. This way works but it does not give a clear and crisp picture on phones. I'm wanting to know what do you guys use when putting backgrounds in on your applications. (ie. Photoshop)

Comment: I think this question doesn't belong here.
 You should use photoshop for creating backgrounds & also you need to read about 9-patch images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Photoshop is better option, but now a days you can make them online if you are not familiar with Photoshop, easily.

Check the following...

[wallcreater](http://www.wallcreator.com/)

[bg patterns](http://bgpatterns.com/)

[x3studios](http://wallpapers.x3studios.com/)

[click this to googled results](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&site=webhp&sa=X&ei=SnCCT6vfAoy3rAfVofjwBQ&ved=0CCQQvwUoAQ&q=online%20background%20maker&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=83489586dc43acf&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=849)

Comment: Thanks, I will try using these online background creators.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop or GIMP would be my first suggestions